# PHP Twitter API 'friendships/destroy' not working

Tags: php, twitter

I am using the https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth library, and it is successfully tweeting, retweeting and following people.

I have now trying to unfollow people, using the following call:

```
$connection->post('friendships/destroy', array('user_id' => $id_str));
```

...where `$id_str` is a twitter user ID.

I'm not receiving any error messags, but the user isn't being removed.

Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: What response *do* you receive?

Comment: When I `echo` the output, I get the full json of the user that I'm trying to unfollow. They're just not being unfollowed.

Comment: @user1259798 Did you find any answer ?